# Cell range according to cell value

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I am trying to copy paste values repeatedly depending on the cell value. I am having problem in my cell range where I would paste the copied value. I used the Do Until Iteration.

I am having trouble in this line: *Range("B1:B(var)").Select*

How can I used the cell value as the ending range of my selected cell?

For example, E1 value is 10. I want it to copy 10 ten times and be pasted only from B1:B10

```
Sub copy_loop()

Dim var As Integer

var = Range("E1").Value
i = 1

Do Until i > var
Range("A1").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("B1:B(var)").Select
ActiveSheet.Paste
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: **1.** It should be `Range("B1:B" & var).Select` **2.** You may also want to see [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba). **3.** Be careful with `Do Until i > var`. You will end up into an endless loop. **4** Since you are working with Excel rows, I recommend using `Long` instead of `Integer`/

Comment: But **where do ou want pasting it**. In your way it will be pasted over the existing range and you will stay in an infinite loop, not incrementing i variable. We know only where from you want pasting. Please, edit your question and better explain **in words** what you try accomplishing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your tags say `excel-formula`, so paste this into `B1`:

```
=TRIM(UNIQUE(A1&REPT(" ",SEQUENCE(E1))))
```

`A1` is your text, and `E1` is the number of repeats.

`UNIQUE` differentiates between `abc` and `abc`  (with a space at the end), so a different number of spaces is added to each text string. `UNIQUE` then spills, and `TRIM` removes any excess spaces.

Comment: Is it possible to do this in a loop? Let's say may first value of E1 is 10, it will be add from rows 1-10, then the value of E2 is 2, then it will be added from rows 11-13.

Answer (score 1):

Please, try the next code. It will paste the range B1:B10 (if E1 value = 10) ten times starting from F1 and going on to G, I, H and so on. No any selection needed:

```
Sub copy_loop()
Dim var As Long, i As Long

var = Range("E1").Value 'supposing it is 10...
i = 1

Do Until i > var
    Range("B1:B" & var).Copy cells(1, 5 + i)
    i = i + 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Do you want pasting in column A:A, each ten rows range below the each other? You did not say anything about **where to paste the range**...

Answer (score 1):

You don't even need a loop to do this, as you can see here:

```
Sub copy_loop()

Dim var As Integer

var = Range("E1").Value
Range("B1:B" & var).Value = Range("A1").Value

End Sub
```

The trick is that you can say for an entire range (like "B1:B20") that all of them need the same value, without even needing a loop.